# What is the Hebrew background of "the word" used in John 1?

Tags: john, hebrew-bible, names-of-god

> **John 1 Life application study Bible**
>
> In Greek philosophy, the Word was the principle of reason that governed the world; in Hebrew thought, the Word was another expression for God.

The Greek use of "logos/word" is well known, but what is this commentary referring to when it says that "in Hebrew thought, the Word was another expression for God"?

Answer (score 0):

The theological literature on this subject is HUGE!!  One can only hope to give the barest introduction to this large and important subject.  Let us begin with some rather simple matters.

**1. LOGOS**

BDAG lists the meaning of the Greek word Λόγος (Logos) as (#3)

> the independent personified expression of God, the Logos, eg, John
> 1:1abc, 14, 1 John 1:1, Rev 19:13.

**2. Parallel with Gen 1:1-4**

There is a striking structural/verbal parallel between John 1:1-4 and Gen 1:1-4; both involve:

- in the beginning
- the word/God spoke/said
- God
- creation
- light
- darkness, etc.

Thus, John 1:1-14 cannot be understood apart from Gen 1 and the meaning that imports to the passage.

**3. The Word**

Possibly a simple summary of the huge literature on this subject and its Hebrew background is given by Albert Barnes:

> **Was the Word** - Greek, "*was the λόγος Logos*." This name is given to him who afterward became "flesh," or was incarnate (John 1:14 -
> that is, to the Messiah.) Whatever is meant by it, therefore, is
> applicable to the Lord Jesus Christ. There have been many opinions
> about the reason why this name was given to the Son of God. It is
> unnecessary to repeat those opinions. The opinion which seems most
> plausible may be expressed as follows:
>
> 1. A "word" is that by which we communicate our will; by which we convey our thoughts; or by which we issue commands the medium of
>    communication with others.
> 2. The Son of God may be called "the Word," because he is the medium by which God promulgates His will and issues His commandments. See
>    Hebrews 1:1-3.
> 3. This term was in use before the time of John.
>
> - (a) It was used in the Aramaic translation of the Old Testament, as, "e. g.," Isaiah 45:12; "I have made the earth, and created man
>   upon it." In the Aramaic it is, "I, 'by my word,' have made," etc.
>   Isaiah 48:13; "mine hand also hath laid the foundation of the earth."
>   In the Aramaic, "'By my word' I have founded the earth." And so in
>   many other places.
> - (b) This term was used by the Jews as applicable to the Messiah. In their writings he was commonly known by the term "Mimra" - that is,
>   "Word;" and no small part of the interpositions of God in defense of
>   the Jewish nation were declared to be by "the Word of God." Thus, in
>   their Targum on Deuteronomy 26:17-18, it is said, "Ye have appointed
>   the word of God a king over you this day, that he may be your God."
> - (c) The term was used by the Jews who were scattered among the Gentiles, and especially those who were conversant with the Greek
>   philosophy.
> - (d) The term was used by the followers of Plato among the Greeks, to denote the Second Person of the Trinity. The Greek term νοῦς nous
>   or "mind," was commonly given to this second person, but it was said
>   that this nous was "the word" or "reason" of the First Person of the
>   Trinity. The term was therefore extensively in use among the Jews and
>   Gentiles before John wrote his Gospel, and it was certain that it
>   would be applied to the Second Person of the Trinity by Christians.
>   whether converted from Judaism or Paganism. It was important,
>   therefore, that the meaning of the term should be settled by an
>   inspired man, and accordingly John, in the commencement of his Gospel,
>   is at much pains to state clearly what is the true doctrine respecting
>   the λόγος Logos, or Word. It is possible, also, that the doctrines of
>   the Gnostics had begun to spread in the time of John. They were an
>   Oriental sect, and held that the λόγος Logos or "Word" was one of the
>   "Aeones" that had been created, and that this one had been united to
>   the man Jesus. If that doctrine had begun then to prevail, it was of
>   the more importance for John to settle the truth in regard to the rank
>   of the Logos or Word. This he has done in such a way that there need
>   be no doubt about its meaning.

Thus, the choice of "logos" to introduce John's gospel was uniquely designed to appeal to both a Hebrew and Greek speaking audience.  For more information see appendix below.

**4. Spoken Word**

Lastly, it should not be forgotten that Logos primarily means (BDAG #1):

> a communication whereby the mind finds expression, word.

Hebrews 1:1-3 takes up this theme by declaring that Jesus Christ was the greatest way that God could find to communicate to humans the divine message of the gospel -

> Heb 1:1-3 - On many past occasions and in many different ways, God
> spoke to our fathers through the prophets. But in these last days He
> has spoken to us by His Son, whom He appointed heir of all things, and
> through whom He made the universe. The Son is the radiance of God’s
> glory and the exact representation of His nature, upholding all things
> by His powerful word. After He had provided purification for sins, He
> sat down at the right hand of the Majesty on high.

**APPENDIX - More on the Word**

The Cambridge commentary offers some further insights:

> In the Old Testament we find the Word or Wisdom of God personified,
> generally as an instrument for executing the Divine Will. We have a
> faint trace of it in the ‘God said’ of Genesis 1:3; Genesis 1:6;
> Genesis 1:9; Genesis 1:11; Genesis 1:14, &c. The personification of
> the Word of God begins to appear in the Psalm 33:6; Psalm 107:20;
> Psalm 119:89; Psalm 147:15. In Proverbs 8, 9 the Wisdom of God is
> personified in very striking terms. This Wisdom is manifested in the
> power and mighty works of God; that God is love is a revelation yet to
> come. (2) In the Apocrypha the personification is more complete than
> in O.T. In Ecclesiasticus (c. b. c. 150–100) Sir 1:1-20, Sir 24:1-22,
> and in the Book of Wisdom (c. b. c. 100) Wis 6:22 to Wis 9:18 we have
> Wisdom strongly personified. In Wis 18:15 the ‘Almighty Word’ of God
> appears as an agent of vengeance. (3) In the Targums, or Aramaic
> paraphrases of O.T., the development is carried still further. These,
> though not yet written down, were in common use among the Jews in our
> Lord’s time; and they were strongly influenced by the growing tendency
> to separate the Godhead from immediate contact with the material
> world. Where Scripture speaks of a direct communication from God to
> man, the Targums substituted the Memra, or ‘Word of God.’ Thus in
> Genesis 3:8-9, instead of ‘they heard the voice of the Lord God,’ the
> Targums have ‘they heard the voice of the Word of the Lord God;’ and
> instead of ‘God called unto Adam,’ they put ‘the Word of the Lord
> called unto Adam,’ and so on. ‘The Word of the Lord’ is said to occur
> 150 times in a single Targum of the Pentateuch. In the theosophy of
> the Alexandrine Jews, which was a compound of theology with philosophy
> and mysticism, we seem to come nearer to a strictly personal view of
> the Divine Word or Wisdom, but really move further away from it.
> Philo, the leading representative of this religious speculation (fl.
> a.d. 40–50), admitted into his philosophy very various, and not always
> harmonious elements. Consequently his conception of the Logos is not
> fixed or clear. On the whole his Logos means some intermediate agency,
> by means of which God created material things and communicated with
> them. But whether this Logos is one Being or more, whether it is
> personal or not, we cannot be sure; and perhaps Philo himself was
> undecided. Certainly his Logos is very different from that of S. John;
> for it is scarcely a Person, and it is not the Messiah. And when we
> note that of the two meanings of Λόγος, Philo dwells most on the side
> which is less prominent, while the Targums insist on that which is
> more prominent in the teaching of S. John, we cannot doubt the source
> of his language. The Logos of Philo is preeminently the Divine Reason.
> The Memra of the Targums is rather the Divine Word; i.e. the Will of
> God manifested in personal action; and this rather than a
> philosophical abstraction of the Divine Intelligence is the starting
> point of S. John’s expression.
>
> To sum up:—the personification of the Divine Word in O.T. is poetical,
> in Philo metaphysical, in S. John historical. The Apocrypha and
> Targums help to fill the chasm between O.T. and Philo; history itself
> fills the far greater chasm which separates all from S. John. Between
> Jewish poetry and Alexandrine speculation on the one hand, and the
> Fourth Gospel on the other, lies the historical fact of the
> Incarnation of the Logos, the life of Jesus Christ.
>
> The Logos of S. John, therefore, is not a mere attribute of God, but
> the Son of God, existing from all eternity, and manifested in space
> and time in the Person of Jesus Christ. In the Logos had been hidden
> from eternity all that God had to say to man; for the Logos was the
> living expression of the nature, purposes, and Will of God. (Comp. the
> impersonal designation of Christ in 1 John 1:1.) Human thought had
> been searching in vain for some means of connecting the finite with
> the Infinite, of making God intelligible to man and leading man up to
> God. S. John knew that he possessed the key to this enigma. He
> therefore took the phrase which human reason had lighted on in its
> gropings, stripped it of its misleading associations, fixed it by
> identifying it with the Christ, and filled it with that fulness of
> meaning which he himself had derived from Christ’s own teaching.

Answer (score 0):

**The quote in the OP probably uses the term "Hebrew" in the ethnic sense rather than the linguistic sense. In other words, it says "Hebrew" but it means "Jewish.**" There is support in the OT for God speaking the world into existence but not for his Word being synonymous with him. *However, there is indeed support for the idea that Jewish thought addressed the concept of logos and applied it theologically.*

The primary source for the "logos" in Jewish thought at the time John's gospel was composed is the writing of **Philo of Alexandria**. However it should be admitted at the outset that Philo wrote in Greek. Although he dealt with the Hebrew scriptures extensively, he seems to have read them in the Septuagint translation, not Hebrew.

Philo was a contemporary of Jesus and one of the most influential men of Alexandria. His works were known primarily to Jews outside of Judea. The idea of the logos comes from Platonic thought and was applied by Philo to God, where the logos is both the agent of creation and a second face of God, similar to the relationship between Moses and Aaron. He also describes the logos as the "first-born son" of God and Sophia (Wisdom). Philo had much more to say about the logos, but these ideas seem to form the important background for the Gospel of John's vision of Jesus as God's Son:

> In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word
> was God. He was with God in the beginning. Through him all things
> were made; without him nothing was made that has been made. In him
> was life, and that life was the light of all mankind.

**The sentence in the OP commentary is poorly expressed. It should have said "Jewish" rather than "Hebrew." Moreover if it refers to Philo's ideas, his thought was not typical. It may have gained popularity among intellectuals in the Greek-speaking Jewish world but it is erroneous to characterize this as "Hebrew thought" generally. Moreover, even Philo did not claim that God and Logos are two words meaning the same thing.**

For more information on Philo's life and thought see [Philo of Alexandria](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/philo/) in the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy.

Comment: Please consider these two statements: *There is support in the OT for God speaking the world into existence but not for his Word being synonymous with him.* and *It should have said "Jewish" rather than "Hebrew."* While insightful, they are both unilateral assertions without evidence. Could you consider using subjuctives like "arguably" or "might have said", otherwise provide an argument or source? It's just rather certain-conclusive for not having an explanation as to why.

Answer (score -1):

**What "'word' used in John 1"?**

I'll assume the question is referring to the logos?

The logos **is not** the same as the Hebrew "word".  It was only translated this way and wrongfully conflated.

The **logos** (specifically introduced in John 1) is a Greek concept that predated John and Jesus. It was thought of as *the cosmic ordering principle; that which pervaded all objects and living things, bestowing on them reason and order*... as you rightly have stated.

John is using this concept to convey the most important function and quality of the Father that was inherited by His only begotten son....the quality of the logos, which was a quality of God and with Him from a beginning.

A Father begets a Son and still is 100% the Father.... No change to Himself. A Son comes forth from the seed of his Father and takes on some of the Fathers roles and functions.

Some liken the logos to the female personified **wisdom** of the Father we read about in Proverbs 8.

> 22 The Lord *possessed me in the beginning of his way*, before his works of old.
> 23 I was set up from everlasting, from the beginning, or ever the earth was.
> 24 When there were no depths, I was brought forth; when there were no fountains abounding with water.
> 25 Before the mountains were settled, before the hills was I brought forth:
> 26 While as yet he had not made the earth, nor the fields, nor the highest part of the dust of the world.
> 27 When he prepared the heavens, I was there: when he set a compass upon the face of the depth:
> 28 When he established the clouds above: when he strengthened the fountains of the deep:
> 29 When he gave to the sea his decree, that the waters should not pass his commandment: when he appointed the foundations of the earth:

An interpretation of the logos being another eternal god other than the Father(YHWH), is polytheism. Don't let anyone convince you otherwise.

Comment: Yes the Greek use of the phrase is clear, but the question is asking for more details about what the commentary says: "in Hebrew thought, the Word was another expression for God."

Comment: @ReadLessPrayMore - Philo of Alexandria called the logos the "first born son" of God and Sophia. Of course he did not mean this literally... more like God + Wisdom resulted in Logos. See my answer for more. Wisdom is a personification of one of God's attributes, not a second God.

Comment: @By what scriptural support are you differentiating God's wisdom from His logos?  Prov 8 supports the conflation of the two.  Not the differentiation.

Comment: @ReadLessPrayMore I don't see a differentiation in Dan's comment. Dan is just delineating details. If you disagree with his answer, quote what you refer to in a comment on that answer.

Comment: @Jesseיִשַׁי "God + Wisdom = Logos.  Therefore Logos is differentiated from Wisdom

Comment: I have plans to add to this answer.  There much more to say and new things I'm learning everyday.

Comment: @ReadLessPrayMore *God + Wisdom = Logos* is interesting, but it needs justified and defended.

Comment: @Jesseיִשַׁי That is NOT my concept.  That is the false concept I am dismantling.  I should dismantle it in the comments for Dan's answer not mine.

Comment: @ReadLessPrayMore Okay, it just looks like you are defending that idea based on how your comment was worded. Probably best to dismantle it in an answer; comments are for clarity of understanding, so your point won't be understood or seen by many. It's not "admin", it's "moderator" and prerequisite is to be elected in a moderator election. What I believe isn't the focus, but you and anyone is welcome to ask in the [site chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1505). We're all over the map now.

Comment: @Jesse...I see what you are saying now.  And your mention of my comment inspired my posted question of the logos.  So thank you.  Are we all over the map?  I'd like to chat theology with anyone who'd take a rational and open ear and I would recipricate.